# How to make terms of service for windows mobile + How do I make a setup msi file?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I want to make a Terms of service that must be accepted before you install the application. How do I do this in Visual Studios 2008.

**Edit**

I want to make a setup msi that will install the application on their phone through active sync. I have the cab file made and ready to go I just need to make the msi file but I am not sure how to get it to work.

I followed this tutorial

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx

and in the end it wants me to install it on my windows 7 not on my mobile device.

Comment: Where do you want it to appear?  On teh device when running the CAB, or on the PC when installing from ActiveSync?

Comment: How does it work with ActiveSync right now I CAB setup wizard thing in my VS2008. How I am doing it right now is I copy it over to my device and then double click on the CAB and install. Later one I want to put it in the app store but not sure how it works. My plan though is when the application starts to install a terms will popup just like all windows applications. You click on the .exe and it starts to install but before it gets to far a terms pops up and you have to accept continue.

Comment: If you want this to be all on-device (which will be required for marketplace) then an MSI is not the right thing for you.  You need a custom installer DLL that creates a Dialog, and that has to be written in C (as you've seen in your other question).

Comment: Yes but I also want a download version on my site. So people have a choice to download from market place or my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct.  The MSI installs on the desktop.  It registers your CAB with ActiveSync, WMDC so that when you attach a device, it gives you the option of installing the application on the device.  The MSI does not run on the device, the CAB does.